# Oracle 12c Insert without indexing but search with index

Tags: oracle, search, indexing, oracle12c, batch-insert

I have a big database with a huge table consisting 80+ fields and 250million of rows. It also has 35 indexes!

This is a big system and cant be shutdown for even a day. So things that I can't do as an immediate solution to optimize performance:

1. Normalization
2. Partitioning
3. Removing indexes
4. Introducing elastics search in parallel.

So we need to have a separate project where we may implement some possibilities that I have mentioned. I was thinking about a way by which temporarily I can handle the issue.

For example, I may have to batch insert 4 million rows after which there wont be no such batch insertion for one year. But while doing so, I cant' drop the indexes as they are used heavily and can cause biggest of issues.

For the batch insertion, I might have used `append` hint in the insertion query so that the indexing for these rows happens later. But I have ten applications running in ten servers for batch insertion, and `append hint` doesn't work for more than one session at a time.

**Objective**

My objective is to insert the data fast ( without indexing those immediately) from ten inserting application. But in the mean time for the old data index to be working properly for search operations. So that search happens quickly.

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried something in dev environment but probably not doing that correctly. I have made those 35 indexes `invisible`. With an intention to  insert fast while keeping the search faster for the data which already existed previously. Is it possible ? I am not getting the search result fast in development environment and couldn't dare to try that in production unless I am 100% sure about what I am doing.

It would be great to have expert opinions (or any suggestion) that might help find a quick fix solution or something we can use over longer period of time.

Comment: `Append hin`t and `invisible index` will not help. For both oracle maintenance indexes during entire process. Invisible indexes are ignored  only by optimizer. Does this table have partitions?

Comment: No partition and as for now , cant introduce partition

Comment: Are you allowed *any* downtime? You could possibly use a partition view until you can implement full partitioning; load your 4 million rows into a new table, add the indexes to that, then (re)create a view that unions that with the original table - which you might have to rename if everything is in one schema. The cutover could be quick but not instant though.